# tcpdump shows vrrp traffic (proto 112) only if keepalived is run on the host

Tags: tcpdump, keepalived

In our LAN we have several keepalived clasters (used different virtual_router_id of course) - all operating on multicast.
The issue is that before installing and running keepalived on particular host I cannot sniff vrrp traffic by tcpdump:

- when I started keepalived - I see ALL vrrp multicast of this LAN
- when I stopped keepalived - tcpdump shows nothing in vrrp

Already checked firewalld, iptabels and sysctl net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind - everything is OK.
OS - RHEL 8.0

The need to see vrrp traffic **before** running keepalived is because we want to generate **unique** virtual_router_id before installing and running keepalived by checking what ids are already taken.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- no run keepalived server: don't use **-i any** and **-p**，more information **man tcpdump**; when your's keepalived instance use **auth_type AH**，proto is ah not vrrp，so suggest you use

**tcpdump -i eth0 net 224.0.0.0/8**

or

**tcpdump -i eth0 vrrp or ah**

- run keepalived server: you can execute **ip maddress show dev eth0**,you will find add some change

  link  01:00:5e:00:00:12

  inet  224.0.0.18

so nic run promiscuity mode you can still capture packets

Comment: Thanks S.Mao. I afraid I didn't understand you. My outputs right now:
# service keepalived start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start keepalived.service
# tcpdump -i ens192 vrrp or ah
listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:43:45.099471 IP 10.11.197.229 > vrrp.mcast.net: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 2, prio 100, authtype none, intvl 1s, length 20
12:43:45.202572 IP 10.11.197.107 > vrrp.mcast.net: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 236, prio 100, authtype none, intvl 1s, length 20
As you see - VRRP protocol cuptured

Comment: After stopping keepalived service - nothing is cuptured by tcpdump:
# service keepalived stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop keepalived.service
# tcpdump -i ens192 vrrp or ah
listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured

Comment: when keepalived stop:

first terminal: tcpdump -i ens192 net 224.0.0.0/8

second termianl: ip -d link show ens192 | grep -i promiscuity

promiscuity 1 will ok, promiscuity 0 is some special configuration of your system

only your nic run promiscuous mode you can capture multicast packets

Comment: Thanks again. promiscuity is 1. Still nothing captured for tcpdump -i ens192 net 224.0.0.0/8

Comment: I added picture from my terminal in original post

Comment: I guess there are some security policies on the switch, can you log in to the switch to confirm the configuration, such as acl; Or you can ask your network administrator

Comment: * ifconfig ens192 allmulti

try tcpdump

* check whether there some acl on the switch 

* capture packets  on the switch if you can

...

anyway, this is a very interesting troubleshooting process, and would love to work with you to solve this problem

Comment: picture 'ip a' and 'ip route'  .   It occurred to me that does your server have multiple nic? If yes, try systecl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0 .